# Server Side Error validation

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

In my application I am doing client side and server side validation. Client side validation is pretty easy and user will not be able to click on the `submitForm` button. But suppose the zip code entered does not match with the order number and server is giving me error in 200 response in angular $http call promise. How can I show the server side error and maintain my validation ?

```
{"result":{"success":false,"code":null,"message":"The entered Zip does not match with Order"},"errors":
   []
```

Answer (score 1):

Might not be the exact answer but could help :

1) On the server side if there are errors you should first stop the script from reaching to database.

2) Populate error messages on the server side in an array in the form of associative array, which can contain field name as key and error message as value. Later send the array to client side in JSON format.

3) On the client side loop through the JSON object to initialise the scope variables that will contain error messages per field.

May be in the format : serverErrors.fieldName.error = 'Error Message from server'

This should be a scope object. And the same object should be rendered on the template per field.  So that when you loop through your JSON and assign error messages to each field it will show up in template. As Angular has two way binding.

This way you will be able to handle custom server side validations and show errors on client side.  And this is possible not just in theory we have implemented this approach in one of our projects.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: And enclose those error variables with span having text colour as red. So it does look like proper errors ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try

```
$http.post('URL', { "ID": ID }).success(function (resultData) {
      if (results.result.success) {
          alert("scuess！");
          $window.location.href = "/";
      }
      else {
          alert(results.result.message)
      }
});
```